# Spring MVC How to pass two parameters and return JSON array using ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, post

These are the String-type parameters I want to send.
I have to send two parameters to DB and use them to query data, and get the data back as JSON array type.
I also got jackson-databind library in my project.

```
  var startDate = picker.startDate.format('YY-MM-DD');
  var endDate = picker.endDate.format('YY-MM-DD');

  var dates = { "startDate": startDate, "endDate": endDate };
```

This is the Ajax code

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "selectCouponByTerm",
            type : "POST",
            data : dates,
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success : function(data){
                dataTable.attr('data', JSON.stringify(data)).trigger("create");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error : function(e){
                console.log(e.status);
            }
        })
```

Then in the controller,

```
  @PostMapping("/selectCouponByTerm")
  @ResponseBody
  public List<Coupon> selectCouponByTerm(@RequestBody String startDate,
                                         @RequestBody String endDate) {
      return "adminService.selectCouponByTerm(startDate, endDate)";
  }
```

it gives me `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to List<Coupon>` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the enclosing double quotes from the return statement

Comment: Now it shows `adminService cannot be resolved`. The controller can't recognize the service interface.

Comment: adminService is a reference of the service object, you need to autowire it in controller, if you are new for the backend coding, I would suggest to check how other controllers are organised in your codebase, or check some online tutorials.

Comment: I forgot to autowired the service. Thank you :)